# Supremum of a set of ordinals

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, supremum-and-infimum, ordinals

The definition of supremum (from wikipedia) is as follows:

If $(P,\le)$ is a partially ordered set and $S$ is a subset of $P$ then $x\in P$ is an upper bound for $S$ if $y\le x$ for all $y\in S$. Further, upper bound $x$ is a supremum for $S$ if whenever $z$ is an upper bound for $S$ then $x\le z$.

Now consider the theorem:

> If $\mathcal C$ is a collection of ordinal numbers then it possesses a
> supremum.

We take the union of all the ordinals and prove it is the supremum. But what is our set $P$ as per the above here? Also, the supremum of the $\omega=\{0,1,2\dots,\}$ is $\omega$ itself, right?

Comment: Correct, the supremum of $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ is $\omega$.  This holds even if you do not use the Von Neumann method of coding the ordinals.  Perhaps it would be confusing to say "the supremum of $\omega$ is $\omega$", since that uses $\omega$ in two different senses: as an ordinal and as a set of ordinals.

Comment: Additionally $\omega$ is often defined as the least upper bound of $\mathbb N$, in which case we get this result straight from the definition.

Comment: $(\cup C)+1=(\cup C)\cup\{\cup C\}=D$ is the least ordinal greater than $\cup C. $ We can let $P$ be any ordinal such that $P\ge D.$ Or if $\max C$ exists we could also let $P=\cup C.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet If you would care to post this as an answer I will accept it.